# Why doesn't QGIS export polygon styling when saving to KML?

Tags: qgis, kml, qgis-2.16

I'm trying to convert shp to kml using the Save As... dialog in QGIS 2.16, but none of the layer styling is appearing in the output kml. I've chosen the 'feature symbology' option, it doesn't seem to do anything. The output is always hollow polygons with a 1px red border. Is this normal behaviour?

Comment: related: [Is there a way to export the style, along with a shapefile, to a kml in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/151188/is-there-a-way-to-export-the-style-along-with-a-shapefile-to-a-kml-in-qgis)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in QGIS and is not working for points and polygons, only works for line. The bug is not yet fixed. Details here: https://hub.qgis.org/issues/13688