# Exporting a grid to KMZ with legend (QGIS 3)

Tags: qgis, google-earth, vector-grid

I am stuck trying to export a grid with values to a KMZ file with a legend that can be viewed in Google Earth Pro.

This is the grid I'm trying to export (it is in EPSG 32756)
[image: Screenshot of Grid in QGIS 3]

This is how I need the KMZ to be displayed and structured in GEP:

[image: How I need the grid to display in GEP]

And this is how the attribute table is constructed:

[image: Attribute table screen shot]

I've tried exporting to KML using polygon grometry but even if I convert the CRS to EPSG 4326 for GEP first, it ends up on the other side of the world, or on top of the north pole, and with pretty much no data in it. Can anyone give me some ideas of how I should be exporting this data?

Comment: Here are a few tests that may help point to where the problem lies. If you load the KML into QGIS, does it display correctly, or on the wrong side of the world? What if you export your layer to a *shapefile* in EPSG 4326 and load it into QGIS?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. FYI I am exporting using "Save Features As ..." from the right click menu and "Feature Symbology". I've just exported again and when I open the KML output in QGIS it is an empty grid but it is in the right location and the data table looks reasonable. But there is no data in the table other than what I exported (although there are other columns), so I don't think it is building a feature symbology at all. It displays now in the right location in GEP but all I have is an empty grid. Each grid cell contains all the data I exported, but there is no color in the cell.

Comment: I also tried using the MMQGIS KML export utility. The KML displays in the right location and has a correctly colored grid (although grid lines are way too thick), but there is almost no feature data in the cells. Only the ID and cell value (which is related to the cell color) are in the cell data.

Comment: It sounds like you're confusing data with symbology. If the attribute table has all the fields and values, then it exported correctly. Symbology must be set manually in Google Earth; QGIS can't export symbology in a format that Google Earth can read.

Comment: Great answer, csk, except it's wrong. MMQGIS can export symbology to KML and it can be displayed in Google Earth Pro without further editing in GEP (I've discovered all this yesterday through experimentation). 

I am now able to do almost everything I was trying to do, but I still don't have the ability to include a legend. Also the grid borders exported by MMQGIS are thick, maybe 2 pts, and if I try to edit them in GEP I lose all the grid colours.

Comment: My comment was based on [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/210105/81764) which received an answer saying QGIS can't export symbology to KML for point and polygon layers. I'm glad to hear that the MMQGIS plugin has fixed that issue. Please consider self-answering this question with the explanation of how you used that plugin to export to kml with style. If you want help fine-tuning the MMQGIS export, that could be a new question.