# Export a QGSVectorLayer as KML format with style

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I have a vector layer with geometry type `PointGeometry` and styled with `QgsGraduatedSymbolRendererV2` renderer.

I have tried:

```
QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer,"kml_example.kml","utf-8",None,"KML")
```

But it only exports points i.e. without colors.

How can I export this vector layer as KML output with colors?

Comment: KML/KMZ doesn't support a lot of symbology options so sometimes it's just impossible to use the same symbology, you can read more https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/151188/is-there-a-way-to-export-the-style-along-with-a-shapefile-to-a-kml-in-qgis