# QGIS transparent polygon returned after digitizing

Tags: qgis, geojson, digitizing, layer-to-kml

After the digitalization of my raster map as per below:

[image]

I saved it in .geojson format and .kml format.

The geoJSON works fine:

[image]

but once I export as a kml and open (in Google MyMaps), then I have borders only:

[image]

In the Google Earth it looks the same.

Is there a step, which I forgot during my digitalization process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's still a filled polygon, however the symbology does not save along with the data. Therefore when you open it in Google Maps / Earth they apply a default or random symbology. You can change this in Google Earth using the following: `right click the layer > properties > style, color`, in Google MyMaps when you hover over the layer a paint bucket will appear, this lets you change the symbology.

EDIT: You may have more luck with this answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/240772/98170

Comment: Yes I can do, as you are saying, but it looks like I have to do it one by one.

Comment: See the link I added to my answer.

Comment: Perfect! It works, thank you a lot!